# local variable x may not have been initialized?

Tags: java

```
    public int getValue(int row, int column) {
    int x;
    if (row == 0 && column == 0) {x = 1;};
    if (row == 0 && column == 1) {x = 2;};
    if (row == 0 && column == 2) {x = 3;};
    if (row == 0 && column == 3) {x = 4;};
    return x;
}
```

why do I get the "local variable x may not have been initialized" error in java? How can I fix this?

Comment: what do you think happens if `x` doesnt match any of the `if` conditions?

Comment: int x is _declared_ but not _initialized_. Your if statements do not guarantee that x will be initialized. Your possible solutions are to rewrite your if statements to have an else block where you can set an x value or return an error code value such as -1, or initialize x with this default error value.